# I am having issues getting the src tags for my js and css files to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am trying to work on a sample web application using HTML5 boostrap express js angular and jquery. I have been fighting with the source tags to the js and css files I am trying to include and just cannot get them to work unless I use one that is hosted online. If any one has some spare time here is what my header code looks like

```
index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

//config
app.set('views', __dirname + '');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

//routes
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('index.html')
});

//server
app.listen(1337,function(){
console.log('ready on port 1337');
})
```

This is a screenshot of of my file stucture

[image]

My server is running in the app.js located in the root folder. I have tried many variations of ../ and no slash and even the ~ to attempt to get this to operate. Thank you for your time in advance.

**EDIT** So while I have been messing around I realized if I open the index.html file without running it on my express server it works just fine. I have updated the code portion above to include my app.js.

**SOLVED**
A big thanks to suchit,dfsq,and Anubhav.
So since I was using express I needed to tell express how to properly path to my static src files "aka the js and css" inside of my app.js. So the answer I provide is only relevent if you are running your application on an express server. I will provide the code that was added to my app.js file and to my index.html file to come to a solution.

```
app.js


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
--------------------------------------------------
index.html


<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Sincerely,

Fred K

Comment: try using: src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"

Comment: I am sorry I have tried that. I went back and tried it again thank your for the attempt but, it was unsuccessful.

Comment: It should be `src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"`. Since looks like index.html and bower_components folder are on the same level.

Comment: Add your app.js code too.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I thought that it should be like your answer dfsq, but that did not seem to work either. Thank you for the timely replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));` to app.js *(it is a configuration)* then link to the static files can be written as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

This assumes all your static files such as javascript and CSS files reside in your `/bower_components` folder.

The statement instructs the app to make `/bower_components` the root for all the static files.

app.js now looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

//config
app.set('views', __dirname + '');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

//routes
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index.html')
});

//server
app.listen(1337,function(){
    console.log('ready on port 1337');
})
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to be what I was looking for I have to run outside will be testing in in about 5-6 minutes and will return let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this worked thank you very much. Sorry express is something I am pretty new to.

Comment: You might want to study about `middlewares` in express and how they work. That is an important part of express.

Comment: Yes I agree that would be a good idea. I am going to take a break from the application and begin looking into that right now. Thank you for your advice.